# Cloud masking for Sentinel-2 Level-1C (Top of Atmosphere) Image Collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, cloud-cover, cloudmasking

This is my code for loading Sentinel-2 Level-1C (TOA) imagery for my defined AOI. It is working perfectly fine. I just want to do cloud masking here so that the mosaic for every 6 month will be a cloud free mosaic. Can .qualityMosaic be applied here so that I do not need cloud masking?

```
var Date_Start = ee.Date('2015-01-01');
var Date_End = ee.Date('2023-05-30');

var num_months_in_interval = 6;
var number_of_months = Date_End.difference(Date_Start,'month').round();
var dates = ee.List.sequence(0, number_of_months, num_months_in_interval);
var make_datelist = function(n) {
  return Date_Start.advance(n,'month');
};
dates = dates.map(make_datelist);

var CreateMosaic = function(d1) {
  var start = ee.Date(d1);
  var end = ee.Date(d1).advance(num_months_in_interval, 'month');
  var date_range = ee.DateRange(start, end);
  return ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED")
    .filterBounds(table)
    .filterDate(date_range)
    .mosaic()
    .clip(table)
};
var List_of_Images = dates.map(CreateMosaic);

var MosaicsCollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(List_of_Images);
```

[image]